# Updating the same column from different columns of another table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am using the following 3 queries to update the status based on the value of 3 different column from another table.

```
UPDATE NUMBER_TABLE  SET STATUS='X'  WHERE STATUS='P' AND NUMBER IN 
            (SELECT NVL(CONTACT_NO,'XXXXXXXXXX') FROM TMP_NUMBER_FOUND WHERE STATUS='P');

UPDATE NUMBER_TABLE  SET STATUS='X'  WHERE  STATUS='P' AND NUMBER IN 
            (SELECT NVL(HOME_NO,'XXXXXXXXXX') FROM TMP_NUMBER_FOUND WHERE STATUS='P');

UPDATE NUMBER_TABLE  SET STATUS='X'  WHERE  STATUS='P' AND NUMBER IN 
            (SELECT NVL(WORK_NO,'XXXXXXXXXX') FROM TMP_NUMBER_FOUND WHERE STATUS='P');
```

All 3 queries are doing full table scan. Can someone suggest a better way of merging 3 queries into one

Comment: Are there actually rows in `NUMBER_TABLE` where `NUMBER`  is `'XXXXXXXXXX'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

NOTE: You said you use those three queries to update...  That is not true. Your queries would not work as written; NUMBER is a reserved Oracle keyword, so you would get compilation errors. When you post, please be very careful what you say. The query I offer below as a solution will also not work, for the same reason. Use your actual column names.

```
UPDATE NUMBER_TABLE n SET STATUS='X'  WHERE STATUS='P' AND EXISTS
   ( SELECT 1 FROM TMP_NUMBER_FOUND t where n.NUMBER = NVL(t.CONTACT_NO, 'XXXXXXXXXX')
                                      or    n.NUMBER = NVL(t.HOME_NO   , 'XXXXXXXXXX')
                                      or    n.NUMBER = NVL(t.WORK_NO   , 'XXXXXXXXXX')
   )
;
```

**Added** based on further information from OP (see comments).

The OP shared the information that there are no numbers equal to `'XXXXXXXXXX'` in his data. In this case, the `NVL(...)` is unnecessary and only wastes time. Comparing to `'XXXXXXXXXX'` in this case will be the same as comparing to `NULL` since comparing to `NULL` never returns `TRUE`. So: **remove** those `NVL` wrappers, they are a big source of slowness.

This will come with another, even greater benefit: the columns `CONTACT_NO`, `HOME_NO` and `WORK_NO` should be indexed if they aren't already, and if they are not surrounded by `NVL(...)`, the indexes can actually be used. There should also be an index on `NUMBER`. The OP said this column is part of the PK but not the first column in the PK and asked if he should make it the first column. The answer is YES - or, if there is a good reason that another column should remain first (perhaps other queries rely on that), then `NUMBER` should get its own index. But if it can be made the first column in the PK, that should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. can i use any kind of hint on this query to make it faster.

Comment: Not sure (usually not). Do you have an index on the  `NUMBER_TABLE.NUMBER` column? Also, the NVL stuff probably takes up a lot of time - do you have many "numbers" in the `NUMBER_TABLE` table with a `NUMBER` value of `'XXXXXXXXXX'`?

Comment: In TMP_NUMBER_FOUND, CONTACT_NO etc can be NULL. That's why I used NVL to filter out NULL columns. I do not have XXXXXXXXXX.
NUMBER_TABLE.NUMBER is part of PK but it is 2nd column of PK. Will making it 1st help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` with Update,

```
UPDATE NUMBER_TABLE  SET STATUS=(CASE when NUMBER IN 
            (SELECT NVL(CONTACT_NO,'XXXXXXXXXX') FROM TMP_NUMBER_FOUND WHERE STATUS='P') AND STATUS='P' then 'X'  
            when NUMBER IN 
            (SELECT NVL(HOME_NO,'XXXXXXXXXX') FROM TMP_NUMBER_FOUND WHERE STATUS='P') AND STATUS='P' then 'X'
              WHEN NUMBER IN  
            (SELECT NVL(WORK_NO,'XXXXXXXXXX') FROM TMP_NUMBER_FOUND WHERE STATUS='P') AND STATUS='P' then 'X' ELSE STATUS END);
```

Comment: This query is setting the status to 'X' for mached rows but also making the status to NULL for exiting 'P' value

Comment: didn't get your second part of concern.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
UPDATE number_table n INNER JOIN tmp_number_found t
                              ON n.number = NVL(t.contact_no, 'XXXXXXXXXX')
                              OR n.number = NVL(t.home_no, 'XXXXXXXXXX')
                              OR n.number = NVL(t.work_no, 'XXXXXXXXXX')
   SET n.status='X'
 WHERE n.status='P'
   AND t.status='P'
;
```

Comment: It did not work. giving error ORA - 00971 missing SET keyword